# Outbound mail filtering against custom black list

Tags: email, filtering

Does anybody have any recommendations on how to filter outgoing email against a custom black list? For example, I have a list of around 400,000 email addresses that I do not want to send email to. Currently the email administrator says he is using a [Sieve](http://sieve.info/) script to filter the outbound email but using it to filter is too slow. We are running Linux and most likely Postfix and also a commercial MTA which was called Ecelerity but is now part of Symantec Message Labs.

Is there a tool that is better/faster than Sieve for filtering outbound email?

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about ["Restricting what users can send mail to off-site destinations"](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html)